# No data fetched for query(table_class).all() - sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to simply do a "select * from table" but it's returning an empty list.

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, text

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgres+psycopg2://postgres:pwd@localhost:5432/postgres"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(engine)

Base = declarative_base()
    
class CPMyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cp.my_table'

    c_id = Column(Integer)
    c_s_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_s = Column(String)
    
db_session = SessionLocal()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

print(db_session.query(CPMyTable).all())
```

Output:

> []

DDL for the table I'm querying is:

```
CREATE TABLE cp.my_table (
    c_id int4 NULL,
    c_s_id serial NOT NULL,
    c_s text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_s_id)
);
```

What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `__table_args__` to specify schema.

```
class CPMyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'cp'}

    c_id = Column(Integer)
    c_s_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_s = Column(String)
```